# Multiple EventDispatcher threads in Swing

Tags: java, swing, awt, edt

In a big project i found in the logs that multiple event dispatcher threads are used after a longer runtime:

```
 multiple Threads :   3x  java.awt.EventDispatchThread  "AWT-EventQueue-{0,1,2}"
```

The log output is from a function to detect multiple threads with similar names. The application is launched via webstart, so one edt might be for the JavaConsole at startup but why are to left?
Are multiple edt active at the same time?

Comment: why is there multiple event dispatcher threads created (question to author of the code), because JVM correctly creates only one, rest is about to debug a big project, hint have look at implementation of SecondaryLoop instead of something wrong in your code

Comment: As far as i oversee the code there is no explicit creation of a edt. but i read about problems when using the java console with webstart because it might spawn an extra edt. Would do mean with secondary loop?

Comment: [SecondaryLoop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html)

Comment: Thanks, i will read that.